# how to update integer value imported from a module in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying a simple interactive table using react, where the table displays a set of details of Books, namely name, price, and stock. The details of the books are stored in a separate JS fine as a module and imported into the component file. Also 'stock' value is saved as a number type in the module. When I try to add or reduce the 'stock' value by one using a button, it doesn't make any changes to the value count.
Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import bookStock from '../Models/books'

class Books extends Component {
    state = { 
        bookList: bookStock
    }
    totalCopies(){
        let sum = 0
        this.state.bookList.forEach(book => (
            sum = sum + book.stock
        ))
        return sum;
    }
    addBookCount = (book) => {
       this.setState({book.stock = book.stock + 1})
    }
    reduceBookCount = book => {
        this.setState({book.stock = book.stock - 1})
    }

    render() { 
        const {length} = this.state.bookList

        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
            <table className="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>No.of Copies</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.bookList.map(book => (
                        <tr key = {book.id}>
                            <td>{book.name}</td>
                            <td>{book.Price}</td>
                            <td>{book.stock}</td>
                            <td><button onClick={() => this.addBookCount(book)} className="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button></td>
                            <td><button onClick={() => this.reduceBookCount(book)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">REDUCE</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                    <br/>
                    <h1>Total No.of Books: {length}</h1>
                    <h1>Total No.of Copies: {this.totalCopies()}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>

         );
    }
}
 
export default Books;
```

How can I increment and decrement the stock value? The totalCopies method is working fine and it displays the total number of copies

Comment: You have to try this `this.setState({...bookList,book.stock : book.stock + 1})`

Comment: Book should have it own class

Comment: Instead of having the bookList as an array, if you can make it into an object, where the key is the bookID, it becomes a tad easier to update, since you won't have to findIndex, get the element, then update etc all. Something like this

`
  ISBN101: {
    id: 'ISBN101',
    name: 'The tale of 2 cities'
  },
  ISBN102: {
    id: 'ISBN102',
    name: 'somebook'
  },
`;

Answer (score 3):

Your state has a bookList state that maintains the bookStock.However

In the `addBookCount` function:

1. You are trying to update the property `book.stock` which doesn't exist in your `state`.
2. Moreover, this isn't the correct way to update the stock.

First, make a copy of the state in a local variable.
Then, find the book passed as an argument into the function in the local variable (bookList).
Update the stock there.
Now, set the local variable as the new state value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import bookStock from '../Models/books'

class Books extends Component {
    state = { 
        bookList: bookStock,
        bookcount: 0,
    }
    totalCopies(){
        let sum = 0
        this.state.bookList.forEach(book => (
            sum = sum + book.stock
        ))
        this.setState({bookcount: sum})
    }
    addBookCount = (book) => {
       this.setState({book.stock = book.stock + 1})
    }
    reduceBookCount = book => {
        this.setState({book.stock = book.stock - 1})
    }

    render() { 
        const {length} = this.state.bookList

        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
            <table className="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>No.of Copies</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.bookList.map(book => (
                        <tr key = {book.id}>
                            <td>{book.name}</td>
                            <td>{book.Price}</td>
                            <td>{book.stock}</td>
                            <td><button onClick={() => this.addBookCount(book)} className="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button></td>
                            <td><button onClick={() => this.reduceBookCount(book)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">REDUCE</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                    <br/>
                    <h1>Total No.of Books: {length}</h1>
                    <h1>Total No.of Copies: {this.state.bookcount}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>

         );
    }
}
 
export default Books;
```

Can you try this

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the way. Thanks everyone for responding me

```
addBookCount = (book) => {
   this.state.bookList.filter(b => b.id === book.id).forEach(bk => bk.stock = bk.stock + 1)
   this.setState({})
}
reduceBookCount = book => {
   this.state.bookList.filter(b => b.id === book.id).forEach(bk => bk.stock = bk.stock - 1)
   this.setState({})
}
```